# how to get image file from local folder and display them on webpage?

Tags: javascript-objects

I am new for javascript and also learning myself js. I used following code to get image files from local folder to webpage but its not working. Please can anyone help me to solve this

```
  Function parentImg()
  {
 Var image1=new image();
 for ( var i=0; i=3; i++)
 {
 Image1.src="image/parentImg/" + i;
 document.getElementById("parent").src=image1;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, "But it's not working" doesn't give us a lot to work out from, include any errors you are getting and what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi, My problem is that images are not getting displayed on webpage. Getting error like " Uncaught reference error: image not defined" at the code line " var image1=new image()".